# how to let my DropDownList ant design Component fixed when I Scroll on my Page

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image: dropDownList]how to let my DropDownList ant design Component fixed when I Scroll on my Page

Comment: use CSS `position: fix;` for the component

Comment: @windmaomao i did it but did not work out